# Capturing exceptions in OpenTelemetry .NET and Sentry.io

Tags: c#, .net, logging, sentry, open-telemetry

I've setup a simple .NET web api appto play around with OpenTelemetry, specifically their .NET SDK of the project.  I've got it working and otel data is feeding into Sentry.io to easily view the trace data.

I'm not a seasoned user of Sentry or OpenTelemetry, but from what I've seen, if an exception/error occurred somewhere in the trace, Sentry would flag where in the flow of things, the error happened. See below example from their site:
[image: Sentry example]

In my app I've designed some controllers and classes that talk to one another in order to get the trace to show different spans.  One of those classes throws an exception (Secure Oder Checks).  Based off the examples on Sentry, I'd expect to see this span/class flagged in red to show this leg of the trace was responsible for the error.

Discovery tab in Sentry:
[image: Discover screen in Sentry.IO]

In the span detail shown below for secure order checks, you'll see that the exception details are caught and logged.  But oddly the Status is still marked as ok. I've followed examples that I've found online where it's recommended to catch the exception, and log it in a controlled way so that OpenTelemetry can deal with it.  For the record I've also tried to throw the error after logging as some examples suggest.  But this just creates a separate entry on the discover dashboard/screen and it doesn't link up into the trace.

Span detail:
[image: Span details]

```
 public static class SecureOrderChecks
{
    public static async Task DoChecks()
    {
        using var activity = DiagnosticsConfig.ActivitySource.StartActivity("Secure Order Checks");
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            throw new Exception("Oops!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            activity?.RecordException(ex);
            activity?.SetStatus(Status.Error.WithDescription(ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs settings for OpenTelemetry and Sentry:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
.WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .AddSource(DiagnosticsConfig.ActivitySource.Name)
        .ConfigureResource(resource => resource
            .AddService(DiagnosticsConfig.ServiceName))
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(option => option.RecordException = true)
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(option => option.RecordException = true)
        .AddSentry()
);

builder.WebHost.UseSentry(options =>
{
    options.Dsn = "https://***removed";
    options.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
    options.EnableTracing = true;
    options.Debug = true;
    options.UseOpenTelemetry();   
   });
```

Nuget packages:
OpenTelemetry v1.5.1
Sentry v3.34

Does anyone know of why this might be happening?  TIA!

Comment: The status OK means you get a response status of 200 OK.  Which means the connection completed and the server returned a response.  Also it means the server didn't find anything wrong with the request.  It could mean the query did not return any results.  For example if you queried a database for data for yesterday and there was no data.  So then the exception is occurring in client because no data was in the body of the response.  So exception is occurring in client trying to process the response data.

Comment: This is likely one for sentry support to answer on how they're interpreting the OpenTelemetry data. OK means the span's work was done, not that there weren't exceptions on the way. You can manually set a span to failed, but just adding an exception event won't do that.

Comment: Saying that, looking at your manually created activity, that should have a span marked as failed. My suggestion would be to also fire up Jaeger in docker and send the opentelemetry data to both, just to see what thar looks like there.

Comment: It looks like the `Span` that is being created in Sentry for that OpenTelemetry `Activity` isn't getting the status set on it correctly by Sentry's .NET OpenTelemetry integration.

I an issue for this with the Sentry .NET SDK team: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/2514

I'll post back as an "Answer" here, once that issue is addressed.

Comment: Note you won't get full symbolication capturing exceptions this way until the following issue is addressed: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/2439#issuecomment-1577314568

Until then, if you want accurate line numbers etc. for exceptions in Sentry, you should capture these using `SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);` instead of `activity?.RecordException(ex);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in that has been fixed in [Sentry.OpenTelemetry version 3.35.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.OpenTelemetry/3.35.0).

For full details see [pull request #2515](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/pull/2515) but the TLDR; is that exceptions that get captured and recorded using `Activity.RecordException` now get correctly pulled through to Sentry as error Spans with most of the things you'd get if those exceptions had been captured with `SentrySdk.CaptureException`.

Comment: Thanks James,  I've just updated to 3.35.1 and there seems to be some movement.  The status is no longer set to 'ok', but rather is now set to 'unknown'.  I just wanted to check if that was right as I've been assuming status would go to 'error', to be in line with otel status code?  My assumption might be totally wrong so thought I'd check :)